# How to add java (javaFX) modules to the default module path?

Tags: java, javafx

I can run the JavaFX app with the following code

```
java -jar --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules {required modules seperated by commas} {path to jar file} myFXapp.jar
```

But how I can add the java module permanently to JVM to run JavaFX dependent app like below

```
java -jar myFXapp.jar
```

Comment: See if this helps.  https://ath3nd.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/packaging-a-multimodule-maven-spring-app-in-a-standalone-jar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a distribution that includes JavaFX like [liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-17-current), or create a custom runtime [using jlink](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular).